# Can I add multi function cam in gazebo?

Tags: gazebo

As the title mention, I want to add a cam that is capable of both segmentation and depth for the agent robot. Is it possible to do it instead of putting 2 cams? If so,how?

The [segmentation camera](https://gazebosim.org/api/sensors/6.0/segmentationcamera_igngazebo.html) I saw, and the version of my gazebo is 11.14.0

Comment: Please edit your post to explain what exactly you mean by "segmentation". Do you know of any existing gazebo plugin that does it? Also tell us exactly which version of gazebo you are using.

Comment: Gazebo 11 is Gazebo Classic, but the segmentation camera plugin you refer to is for Gazebo Sim. See [here](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/104688/why-does-my-gazebo-saved-the-world-as-plain-text-file/104776#104776) for further info on 'Classic' vs 'Sim'.

Comment: @JRTG btw is it possible to run sim in a virtual environment like docker or conda? I don't want to delete the classic one already installed in my system.

Comment: Up to Gazebo Sim Fortress, Gazebo Sim and Classic can be installed side by side. For more recent Gazebo Sim versions, this is not posible since both use the `gz` command line tool. The [installation instructions](https://gazebosim.org/docs/harmonic/install_ubuntu) propose as workaround "to install from source or to use [Docker gazebo-classic](https://hub.docker.com/_/gazebo) so they are not installed side-by-side on the same system.". Instructions to compile from source are [here](https://gazebosim.org/docs/harmonic/install_ubuntu_src).

Comment: @JRTG I'm using ros1 which fortress being the last version supporting it and seg cam required at least fortress, it seems like fortress is my only option. Trying ubuntu source install, thanks for your help.

Comment: @JRTG It seems like [ubuntu source install](https://gazebosim.org/docs/fortress/install_ubuntu_src) needed ros2? I thought the chart in [it](https://gazebosim.org/docs/garden/ros_installation) said ros1 is available for fortress too.

Comment: No, only `vstool` and `colcon` are needed. Note that it should be possible to also co-install Fortress and Classic both from packages. So source build is not strictly necessary for Fortress. I think you _will_ need to compile the `ros_gz_bridge` from source though, see [here](https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz/tree/noetic).