# why does my gazebo saved the world as plain text file?

Tags: gazebo

As the title mention, when I saved my world it only genarates a plain text file instead of .world file.  Though I still can open the world by `rosrun gazebo_ros gazebo <world_name>`, I got into trouble when trying to launch rviz with gazebo, which all kinds of tutorials required .world file.

edit:

I can change the file to .world file and still launch it using `rosrun gazebo_ros gazebo <world_name>`, but the code doesn't seem like a .world file format. And I'm kinda confused that many tutorials also mentioned launch file, so am I suppose to make it into a package? I just created the whole world only using gazebo.
The [file](https://github.com/brian2lee/test/blob/master/test_depth2.world) it generated using `file->save world as`

gazebo version 11.14.0

Comment: What happens if you rename the plain text file yourself, manually?

Comment: Can you please show how you're process is to get this behavior so we can reproduce it? Especially the options/arguments that you're passing and the filenames and contents you're getting out.  Exactly the commands your running or screenshots of your interactions would be helpful. Without knowing what exactly is happening it's hard to say why.

Comment: It would be great to know also the version you are using in order to see if there is some kind of bug on that distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have specific questions wrt certain tutorials, you should post a link to those tutorials and describe what commands you try and what exact issues you run into.

But apart from that:

- Gazebo loads its environment from an SDF file, which is an xml file (i.e. a *text* file). There are no binary files. It can be called `file.sdf` or `file.world`, but the contents is always xml corresponding to the SDF specification.
- The SDF specification can be found on [sdformat.org](http://sdformat.org/spec).
- Gazebo **Classic** tutorials are [here](https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials). Gazebo Classic is the 'old Gazebo'. It has version *numbers*. The most recent version is 11.
- Gazebo **Sim** tutorials are [here](https://gazebosim.org/docs/harmonic/tutorials). Gazebo Sim is the 'new Gazebo'. It has version *names*, e.g. Fortress, Garden, Harmonic.

  Gazebo Sim used to be called 'Ignition Gazebo' until Fortress. From Garden on the name was changed to 'Gazebo Sim' due to trademark issued wrt 'Ignition'.
- Gazebo and RViz are not the same. You cannot load an SDF into RViz.

> And I'm kinda confused that many tutorials also mentioned launch file, so am I suppose to make it into a package?

A launch file is nothing more than a convenience script to start up your application.

Instead of using a launch script, you can issue each command manually from a terminal (i.e. execute `ros2 run <package> <executable> <arguments>` for each node, start gazebo, etc.).

I think you should start with:

- Gazebo tutorials (i.e. without ROS),
- ROS tutorials (i.e. without Gazebo),
- Play around with these until you get comfortable,
- Learn the basics of launch files,
- Then go through the ROS+Gazebo tutorials.

If that does not work, consider enrolling for a course.

There is no shortcut in learning ROS and Gazebo.